# Convert 32 bit fixed point value

Tags: java, fixed-point

In my Java application I need to interpret a 32 Bit Fixed Point value. The number format is as follows: The first 15 bits describe the places *before* the comma/point, the 16th bit represents the *sign* of the value and the following 16 bits describe the decimal places (1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,...).

The input is a byte array with four values. The order of the bits in the byte array is *little* endian.

How can I convert such a number into Java `float` ?

Comment: What is the input format? byte[] ? String?

Comment: input is given in a byte[] array

Comment: could you please include a set of expected input (in hexadecimals) and output in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do exactly what it says. Assume `x` is the 32bit fixed point number as `int`.

So, put the bits after the point, after the point, and don't use the sign here:

```
float f = (float)(x & 0x7fff_ffff) / (float)(1 << 16);
```

Put back the sign:

```
return x < 0 ? -f : f;
```

You will lose some precision. A `float` does not have 31 bits of precision, but your input does. It's easily adapted to `double`s though.

---

Since the sign bit is apparently really in the middle, first get it out:

```
int sign = x & (1 << 16);
```

Join the two runs of non-sign bits:

```
x = (x & 0xFFFF) | ((x >> 1) & 0x7fff0000);
```

Then do more or less the old thing:

```
float f = (float)x / (float)(1 << 16);
return sign == 0 ? f : -f;
```

---

In case your input is little endian format, use the following approach to generate `x`:

```
int x = ByteBuffer.wrap(weirdFixedPoint).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

where `weirdFixedPoint` is the byte array containing the 32 bit binary representation.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html float has 32 bit of precision, no?

Comment: @GrigoryKalabin it's 32 bits in total, that includes a sign bit and exponent bits. It doesn't have 32 bits in its significant.

Comment: @harold OP said sign was in *16th bit*, so I believe this is incorrect. You seem to assume sign in bit 0 (MSB). Or am I misunderstand something..?

Comment: @haraldK I interpreted that as 16th bit before the point, putting it in the middle would be highly unusual. But who knows. If OP confirms, I'll update it.

Comment: Using `double` instead would indeed be better. Note that in Java `double` is in general the default floating point type,

Comment: @harold I agree. Makes sense.

Comment: thank you for this answer. Indeed, I mean that the 16th bit (in the middle), should be treated as a sign bit. Loosing precision isn't that bad, I only need about 2 decimal places anyways...

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the data format is little endian. Would this make any difference? because somehow i'm still not getting the correct values using, your approach

Comment: @user1291235 if it's still wrong after taking the byte order into account, could you give some examples of correct conversions?

Comment: I've edited the answer. I'm still presuming that the bits *in the byte* have their highest bit on the left. Bit fiddling is fun, isn't it?

Comment: Note that there is also [`reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverse(int)) if all the bits are completely inverted. Instead of little endian order for `ByteBuffer`, the `Integer` class also contains `reverseBytes`.

Comment: The strange thing is, that if I convert a series of values for example from 0 up to 500 the convertion is correct until a value of 250, from then on it converts 251 to -1, 252 to -2, and so on.... I believe your approach is correct, so I guess the problem lies somewhere else... I will do some test and talk to you again as soon as I know what's wrong... thank you

Comment: @user1291235 examples really would help a lot. Just dump 30 random values or so, I should be able to infer the pattern.

Comment: Holy Moly. I guess you were right with your argument that putting the sign bit right in the middle. It seems that it was a misinformation. So interpreting it as 16th bit before the point solved the problem... I will test it with different values as soon as possible and accept your answer. Thank you very much for your willingness to help and your patience. :-)